# In Amadeus, Booking failure due to "TABLE DOES NOT EXIST" error

Tags: amadeus

In the Amadeus Booking confirmation scenario, the FOP web service API throws a "TABLE DOES NOT EXIST" error when using a card or check payment.

Please clarify for us why this error happens when using the FOP api, because we weren't aware of this before, so I would request a clear clarification from the Amadeus technical support team or someone should help this out.

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from the Amadeus Help Desk support team.

> I found some information on the error. From one of the payment developers:
>
> “ most probably an error linked to your point of sale that is not tied
> to a “FOP Table” which defines the list of methods of payments and
> their structure”

As suggested by the Amadeus Help Desk support team, the PCC-owned account manager configured the wrong input data in the FOP table and that is the reason it throws "TAOBLE DOESN'T EXIST".

If they are configured wrongly, the table will consider NAN, so it would require a proper Yes or No input data to configure properly.